# UITextView background image does not fit in frame size of UITextView frame

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uitextview

I am developing an app where I need to put a UITextView for the large text. I have a background image of size 180X89(same as UITextView frame size). When put the image behind the UITextView, everything appears good however, when the user hits the text area and keyboard appears, the cursor appears just outside the edge of the image.

I want the cursor to be appeared in textbox.

**Code for getting UITextview**

```
CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectMake(125.0f, 155.0f, 180.0f, 90.0f);
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];
textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:  @"textbox.png"]];
textView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

[image: image of textbox which I am using for background]
[image: Screen shots showing cursor on left corner outside the background image]

Comment: Instead fo setting it as a background image try placing textView on an imageview where iamgeView.image = backgroundImage

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIImage     *bgImage     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"textbox.png"];
UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];

CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectMake(125.0f, 155.0f, 180.0f, 90.0f);
bgImageView.frame    = textViewFrame;

UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewFrame];

textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textView.delegate      = self;

[self.view addSubview:bgImageView];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple approach. Just use UIImageView behind the TextView and set UITextView Background color as clear color.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in such situations is to make the size of the `UITextView` a bit smaller so that it just comes in ur background image and also give the `UITextView` a corner radius using the framework `<QuartzCore>` like `textview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;` (import the header for the framework). This approach would also give the `UITextView` edges a bit of roundness to make it look like the image u provided above.

So, in short add the `UIImageView` then add the `UITextView` above it and make the background of the textview as clearcolor . Hope this helps !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add UIImageView on your view, Then add UITextView on UIImageView with inner frame of

```
CGPointMake(10,10) as Origin
```

and `CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width - 20.0, imageView.frame.size.hieght - 20.0) as Size` of textView.

Comment: How would I do that? Could you please let me know the codes for doing that.
Now I am able to place the cursor inside the textbox however the letter is still clipped.
   I placed the UIImageView and on top of that I put UiTextView and made 
    textView.layer.cornerradious = 50;

Comment: Edited the @glyytchy Answer. Check it.